# Получить идентификатор пользователя активного листа

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

начал изучать google apps script. Появился такой вопрос.Можно ли узнать какой нибудь идентификатор пользователя активного листа в Google sheets (таблицах) с помощью скрипта? Почту, ид номер, что нибудь, что может быть статитическое у пользователя данного листа. После того как узнаю ИД хочу написать сценарий что-то типа если ИД такой-то то присвоить значение «Андрей» и по логике моего скрипта если этот «Андрей» запустил выполнение сценария то в выбранный диапазон записалась инфа «Андрей». Спасибо всем кто может помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить email юзера, который запустил скрипт ( с некоторыми ограничениями, которые описаны в документации )
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session?hl=ru#getActiveUser() .  Сам метод получения email -  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user?hl=ru#getEmail()